# Matplotlib subplot content disappears using set_xlim, set_ylim

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to construct a plot where I have a fixed number of rows but differing number of columns for each row. The code I use for plotting is equivalent to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
pl.figure()
pl.ion()
pl.subplot(2,1,1)
pl.title("Sets the title for top plot")

plotData(data[0]) # Function that plots data in this first row

for i in range(3):
    pl.subplot(2,3,4+i)
    pl.title("Sets the title of each subplot in second row")
    plotData(data[i+1]) # Plots the data in second row
```

Now for some reason the data plotted in the subplots of the second row disappears. When I debug it it seems as it is there until returning from the plotData() function within the for-loop (or possibly upon calling 
the next subplot command - but this does not explaing why the last subplot is empty ...).

### EDIT:

There was code at the end of the `plotData()` function that triggered the problem:

```
pl.gca().set_xlim(0,15)
pl.gca().set_ylim(0,15)
```

Does this mean that I can not set the x,y-limits after plotting the data, or what am I doing wrong here?

A pastebin of the minimal example showing the problem can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ygvCppLN)

Comment: I'd suggest you try upgrading matplotlib: from what I remember, changing from `0.99` to even to `1.0.1` fixed a *lot* of functionality, `ion()` included.

Comment: @Zhenya Ok, I might try that if it is indeed a bug in matplotlib rather than problem in my code. Apparently it is matplotlib 1.1 in Ubuntu 12.04 and I guess I might be due for a system upgrade anyway ... I have just been reluctant to do it since my system works great atm :-)

Comment: Well, upgrading matplotlib on Lucid is surprisingly smooth (I'm still on Lucid BTW)

Comment: Hmm, when building latest matplotlib (after building numpy 1.6.2 and freetype2 from source) I get an error that g++ can not find the z library (cannot find -lz)) ... anything you know about?

Comment: No, I don't. What I do seem to recall, you need to cleanly `apt-get remove` uninstall the older version of matplotlib.

Comment: `apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib` did the trick. However unfortunately I have the same problem with v1.2

Comment: would you please post a self-contained, runnable example to play with?

Comment: In assembling the self-contained example I found the problematic lines of code: `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, that was embarrassing. If you take a look at the code on pastebin the problem was that the xlim and ylim that I was setting did not take into account the fact that I switched direction of the coordinate system (in y-direction). In `plotData()`:

```
for i,dset in enumerate(data):
    x = np.array([point['x'] for point in dset])
    y = np.array([-point['y'] for point in dset])
```

My calls to `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` did exactly what they were supposed to, it was just that with the limits I set the data was no longer visible in these plots (since I switched the sign of the y-axis on the data but not on the limits).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Zhenya - I don't see this functionality with the latest matplotlib (the development version 1.3-dev and suspect it is fixed in at least v1.2.0, but maybe even as early as v1.0.1).

HTH,

**UPDATE: Added output from mpl v1.2.0**:

```
> python
Python 2.7.2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print matplotlib.__version__
1.2.0
>>> 
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> 
>>> plt.ion()
>>> 
>>> plt.subplot(2,1,1)
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x283d790>
>>> plt.title("Sets the title for top pltot")
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x2851f50>
>>> 
>>> plt.plot(range(10, 0, -1))
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2c40790>]
>>> 
>>> for i in range(3):
...     plt.subplot(2,3,4+i)
...     plt.title("Sets the title of each subplot in second row")
...     plt.plot(range(10))
... 
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x2c40e90>
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x2c64a90>
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2c6e990>]
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x2c6ec10>
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x2e6c810>
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2e78110>]
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x2e78390>
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x2e8ced0>
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2e98610>]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem with v1.2

Comment: Seems to work for me. See my update - if your still having problems, please let me know your machine/OS python version etc.

Comment: Sorry, as I was writing the minimal example to show the error I found that it was actually my calls to `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`that were causing the content to disappear. I also added the example as a pastebin to the OP.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Your answer helped me in realizing that it was nothing wrong the with the actual calls to matplotlib.